# Вернуть объект на прежнюю позицию SVG

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg, анимация

Есть объект, который я анимирую с помощью `animateMotion`. После клика на кнопку остановки анимации `stop` объект должен вернуться на прежнее место, где он бы отрендерился без той же анимации, в данном случае `x` & `y` = 0, но при остановке анимации объект сохраняет своё местоположение, чего фактически не должно быть. Может я неправильно пытаюсь отключить анимацию, изменяю атрибут(`xlink:href`), принимающий объект, который будет двигаться вдоль пути, то есть квадрат, который есть в примере ниже. Может быть есть какие-то встроенные функции для `SVG`, в чём я очень сильно сомневаюсь, хотелось бы услышать вразумительный ответ по этому поводу.

Минимальный пример:

```js
document.querySelector('button').onclick = () => {
  document.querySelector('#AM').setAttribute('xlink:href', '  ');
};
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" style="border: 0.0625rem solid">
    <g class="main-area">
      <path d="M0 75L300 75" fill="none" stroke="red" id="AMP"/>
      <rect x="0" y="0" width="50" height="50" id="TrO" transform="translate(0 -25)"/>
      <animateMotion id="AM" xlink:href="#TrO" begin="0s" dur="3s" repeatCount="indefinite">
        <mpath xlink:href="#AMP"/>
      </animateMotion>
    </g>
  </svg>
  <button>Stop</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Интересный вопрос...

Comment: @Air, да, пожалуй. Можно ли назвать это багом `SVG`? Вот незадача=)

Comment: Arthur, я не изучал его так глубоко, чтобы иметь право говорить о баге...Кстати, на мой взгляд, JS довольно-таки умный язык и динамический развивается. Может и не  баг, а осмысленное поведение и у него есть свое изящное   решение...  Вот пару решений привел Stepan Kasyanenko

Comment: Красивая цифра в репе))))))))

Comment: @Air Вот и я не плюсую Артуру пока, чтобы не испортить. В нашем чате с утра сохранил скрин на память :-)

Comment: @Alexandr_TT, поди уже сговорился со всеми, чтобы меня не плюсовали 

Comment: @Arthur Да не сговаривался я ни с кем :) Просто плюсуют люди в последнее время оч. сдержанно.А вопрос хорош, ты проснулся уже, можно и плюсануть

Comment: @Alexandr_TT, я же шучу :) Меня не интересует репутация в последнее время)))

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Конечно, не самый лучший вариант, но работу свою делает.

```js
document.querySelector('button').onclick = () => {
  const am = document.querySelector('#AM');
  am.querySelector('mpath').setAttribute('xlink:href', '#AMP1');
  am.setAttribute('repeatCount', '0');
};
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" style="border: 0.0625rem solid">
    <g class="main-area">
      <path d="M0 75L300 75" fill="none" stroke="red" id="AMP"/>
      <path d="M0 75" fill="none" stroke="red" id="AMP1"/>
      <rect x="0" y="0" width="50" height="50" id="TrO" transform="translate(0 -25)"/>
      <animateMotion id="AM" xlink:href="#TrO" begin="0s" dur="3s" repeatCount="indefinite" fill='freeze'>
        <mpath xlink:href="#AMP"/>
      </animateMotion>
    </g>
  </svg>
  <button>Stop</button>
</div>
```

Также есть специальный метод `endElement()`, который останавливает анимацию.

```js
document.querySelector('button').onclick = () => {
  document.querySelector('#AM').endElement();
};
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" style="border: 0.0625rem solid">
    <g class="main-area">
      <path d="M0 75L300 75" fill="none" stroke="red" id="AMP"/>
      <path d="M0 75" fill="none" stroke="red" id="AMP1"/>
      <rect x="0" y="0" width="50" height="50" id="TrO" transform="translate(0 -25)"/>
      <animateMotion id="AM" xlink:href="#TrO" begin="0s" dur="3s" repeatCount="indefinite" fill='remove'>
        <mpath xlink:href="#AMP"/>
      </animateMotion>
    </g>
  </svg>
  <button>Stop</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Добрый вечер, в скором времени отвечу, помогло ли в моём случае ваше решение, я с 90% точностью могу сказать что должно помочь, благодарю за ответ 

Comment: Всё вышло, спасибо за помощь)

Answer (score 5):

### Pure SVG

Можно попробовать другой вид анимации, где будет анимироваться атрибут "x" координата ыерхнего левого угла прямоугольника.

```
<animate id="AM" attributeName="x" values="0;300" begin="play.click" end="stop.click" dur="3s" repeatCount="indefinite">
```

В зависимости от поставленной задачи кнопку `Play` можно убрать.

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" style="border: 0.0625rem solid">
  
<polyline points="0,75 300,75" stroke="crimson" />
 <g class="main-area">
  <rect x="0" y="50" width="50" height="50" id="TrO" >
   <animate id="AM" 
    attributeName="x" 
    values="0;300"
    begin="play.click" 
    end="stop.click" 
    dur="3s"
    repeatCount="indefinite">
   </animate>
  </rect>
 </g>
   <g id="stop">
     <rect id="btn1" 
      x="240" y="120" 
      width="50" height="20"
      fill="#d3d3d3" 
      stroke="black"/>
 <text x="250" y="135" font-size="16">Stop</text>
   </g>
 <g id="play">
  <rect id="btn2"
          x="180" y="120"
          width="50" height="20"
          fill="#d3d3d3" 
          stroke="black"/>
     <text x="190" y="135" font-size="16">Play</text>
 </g>
  
  </svg>
  </div>
```

*Вариант с анимацией `animateMotion`*

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" style="border: 0.0625rem solid">
    <g class="main-area">
      <path d="M0 75L300 75" fill="none" stroke="red" id="AMP"/>
        <rect id="TrO"
         transform="translate(0 -25)"
          x="0" y="0" 
          width="50"
         height="50" />
      <animateMotion id="AM" 
          xlink:href="#TrO" 
   begin="play.click" 
   end="stop.click" 
   dur="3s" 
   repeatCount="indefinite">
        <mpath xlink:href="#AMP"/>
      </animateMotion>
    </g>
    
 <g id="stop">
   <rect id="btn1" 
    x="240" y="120" 
           width="50" height="20" 
   fill="#d3d3d3" 
 stroke="black"/>
 <text x="250" y="135" font-size="16">Stop</text>
 </g>
   <g id="play">
        <rect id="btn2" 
       x="180" y="120" 
       width="50"
              height="20" 
             fill="#d3d3d3"
             stroke="black"/>
 <text x="190" y="135" font-size="16">Play</text>
 </g>
 </svg>

</div>
```

**Update 9.12.2018**

Отформатирован SVG код в стиле CSS правил для более легкого восприятия

Comment: Все же мощная вещь `SVG`...  Столько примочек у нее..

Comment: @Air Да oч. интересная эта штука SVG :) а в комплексе с JS+CSS просто фантастика